# Clearing values corresponding to a column in multiple excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have 300 excel sheets with 20 columns(Including a column "Status"). I want to clear values to blank corresponding to the column "Status" from all the excel sheets without opening each of them. Currently i use to do this manually, but it is time consuming. Please suggest the best solution for this. Can it be done using a macro?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.  Read [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to improve your question.

Comment: To answer your question, yes this can be done with a macro.  That's likely the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be as follows, this assumes that the column you want to clear is Column A, and the clearing takes place from Row 2 to the last row:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to optimize the processing speed
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'change to manual to optimize the running of the code

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through worksheets
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    'get the last row with data in each worksheet
    ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Clear 
    'clear the specified range, in this case from Row 2 to Last
Next ws

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'enable automatic calculations once code has finishe
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 're-set the screen updating
End Sub
```

Comment: Do we need to run this macro for each excel sheet.. Is there a possibility we can provide sheet name and excel file location and at a time we can clean the field values from 300 excel sheets.

Comment: This macro will loop through all the worksheets in your workbook/spreadsheet, of course you can amend it to do so on only given sheets too, but I believe I have already answered your initial question with this code...